# Not getting facebook email

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK for build an website with some facebook integration and I'm having some problems with getting the email from an facebook user.

I ask for these permissions:

```
email,user_birthday,user_about_me,user_relationships,publish_stream,offline_access,user_location
```

And when asking for fields I ask for these:

```
id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,picture,email,birthday,location,gender,friends,bio
```

This is allready live an in most cases there is no problem at all. But in some cases about 1/100 I don't get the email field but all the others fields are there.

Do any one know how this can happen?

I tested with different privacy settings and with multiple facebook accounts.

Ole Dallerup Sørensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution to my problem for now.
Instead of using the graph api I run an fql query and this gives me the email.

the fql:

```
SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, some people have their privacy settings set up so that Facebook proxies any emails to them. This means despite them granting you the permission you will still not get their email address.

Comment: Well if they set there email to an proxey email I will get an email just an xxxx@facebook.com something. In my case the email field is not there == null

Comment: The graph API is extremely buggy, you may wish to file this as a Bug to Facebook as I have seen this sort of question asked many times with no known reason for it